# How do I make just the image clickable and not the whole div?

Tags: css, html, hyperlink

```
<div class="r1">
    <a href="http://..."><img src="..." />
        <div class="text1">TEXT</div>
    </a>
</div>
```

This is the mark up I am using.  The problem I am having is that the DIV (the whole box) is becoming a hyperlink.  I only want the image to hyperlink.  The images I am using are more like triangles in a circle so you have some over lap of the boxed div.

The text portion is in a div [because I am a newb and that made since to me to put it like that] and also because the words are at angles for example like a 44 degree angle to fit inside the triangle like images.

Answer (score 3):

Your div is reacting to hyperlink cause you have whole inner div inside the `a` tag. Try shifting `</a>` at the end of `<img>` tag. Something like this:

```
<div class="r1">
    <a href="http://..."><img src="..." /></a>
    <div class="text1">
         TEXT
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Based on your comment, it seems like you want to have hyperlink on both image and text. If so then what you are doing is perfectly fine. It might visually look like you clicked on whole outer div, but you did not clicked on outer div you actually clicked on contents inside it, it's because you don't have anything else inside outer div.

Comment: Still the same problem. Now the words aren't linking (which would make since)

Comment: Sorry if I am not explaining this well.  Imagine 5 triangles all separate images where the points of the triangles point to the middle.  Each one of these images needs to by a link.  But the div makes an imaginary box around the image.  These boxes over lap the other images, so when you click on one of the triangles it actually opens up a different one.  I want the words inside the div to be linkable too. SO basically I want the image and the word, but not the transparent part.

Comment: @TimCooley is diff images and div overlaps each other? And when you try to click on some image, it responds click on overlapping image/div?

Comment: Yes . . .  http://coolefitness.com/  please check out that link, I am sure that is bad form, but you will get the idea when you get there.  If you go to the bottom image in the wheel (the purple one called "pilates") you can see that if you were to mouse over the BLUE "Stretch" (in the corner where the triangle point would be [in the middle of the circle] would come together) and CLICK and DRAG drag the image.  The purple one moves and not the blue.  I hope this helps.

Comment: @TimCooley hmm.. I understand it now. Still some doubts about layout coding. Why you display text inside one div into some other div. I mean text written with purple image (where STRETCH is written) in code is shown inside green image (FULL BODY). Why you do this? Can't you show text inside inner div on same image.

Comment: Yeah I just fixed all of that :-)  Someone else did that coding and messed up what i did so it is correct now.

Comment: http://coolefitness.com/top.html  I just made this so you can see the real problem and all the regular coding is working.  In this example a video will open up when you click on the buttons.  But if you get in the wrong place the wrong video will open.  I hope this really helps.

Comment: No I still have the div overlaying problem.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @TimCooley I guess it's due to your image size. Although it has trnasparent part, but div around it is assigned with width and height of all image with transparent part. So images gets overlap and click on it reacts weirdly.

Comment: yup . . . I guess I will just have to deal with it.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<div class="r1">
    <a href="http://..."><img src="..." /></a>
        <div class="text1">
            TEXT
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

your syntax was wrong try this.......

```
  <div class="r1">
  <a href="http://..."><img src="..." /></a>
  <div class="text1">
        TEXT
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div class="r1">
<a href="http://..."><img src="..." /></a>
<div class="text1">
TEXT
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code..

```
<div class="r1">
  <div>   
     <a href="http://..."><img src="..." /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="text1">
    TEXT
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey now used to this as like this

**HTml**

```
<div class="r1">
    <a href="http://..."><img src="..." /></a>
    <div class="text1">
         TEXT
    </div>
</div>
```

and now **css** used to this

```
.r1 > a{
display:inline-block;
}

.r1 > a, .r1 > a img{
vertical-align:top;
}
```